# Where is a good place to post an 800 word essay on encouragement

Tags: publishing, marketing

I want to write a book that's encouraging, and I have the first chapter, which is a little encouragement on just being alive.

It's 800 words, and I'd like to upload/post it on some web, blog, or forum to see what people think.

Comment: Will you be bringing your own audience (so you need something more like hosting), or are you looking for a place with an audience (so you need something more like a community or publisher)?

Answer (score 3):

I love [Medium](http://medium.com). It's a great site to read short and long essays.

Answer (score 1):

Try
http://hubpages.com/ -- previously squidoo.com 
Pick the proper category and publish your article there for free and maybe generate a lot of interest.

Here's a good article which will provide you with more places where you may be able to publish articles like this:
http://www.lifehack.org/articles/work/20-websites-you-cant-miss-you-want-make-money-freelancer.html

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest Medium, but since it's already proposed by @Lehi, here is another place to share your thought: [Thought Catalog](http://thoughtcatalog.com/submissions/) an independent digital magazine.